# Button not working well using fragments and view pager on all devices

Tags: android

In my application I use 2 fragments in one activity and I have A common
button for both fragments, and I use A ViewPager with SectionsPagerAdapter.

**this code works fine with my LG g3**, but on older devices the button listener is inactive on startup and the text on it is of the other fragment.
and also works well after swipe once between the fragments

the `onCreate` function code:`

```
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    // listener on page selected - for each fragment
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

        // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           setSendButton(position);
        }

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            // Code goes here
        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            // Code goes here
        }
    });


    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    setSendButton(0);


    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(sendMod == 0) {
                setUnitConfigurationByte(getUnitConfigurationByte());
                //  setFlowSetPointByte(getFlowSetPointBytes())
                writeConfiguration();
            }
            else
            {
                flowSetPointFragment.sendPPvCommand();
            }


        }

    });
}
```

the pager class code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0: {
                unitConfigurationFragment = new UnitConfigurationFragment();
                setSendButton(0);
                return unitConfigurationFragment;
            }
            case 1: {
                flowSetPointFragment = new FlowSetPointFragment();
                setSendButton(1);
                return flowSetPointFragment;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                setSendButton(0);
                return "UNIT CONFIGURATION";


            case 1:
                setSendButton(1);
                return "PULSE PER VOLUME";
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

and the setter to the button

```
   public void setSendButton(int fragment) {
    if (fragment == 0) {
        sendButton.setText("send units");
        sendMod = 0;
    }
    if (fragment == 1) {
        sendButton.setText("send pulse per volume");
        sendMod = 1;
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***    The OnClick listener:

```
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(sendMod == 0) {
                setUnitConfigurationByte(getUnitConfigurationByte());
                //  setFlowSetPointByte(getFlowSetPointBytes())
                writeConfiguration();
            }
            else
            {
                flowSetPointFragment.sendPPvCommand();
            }


        }

    });
```

THANK YOU ALL!!!

Comment: Your button seems ok, may the function inside onClick have some problems.

Comment: I've edited and added the OnClick listener.